# SSI to concatenate the echoed variable and/or strip whitespace?

Tags: apache, concatenation, strip, ssi, server-side-includes

The code below, yields the output of "apple banana cantaloupe" (spaces) .

```
<!--#set var="x" value="apple banana cantaloupe" -->
<!--#echo var="x" -->
```

Here's my example: http://4mo.st/my-question.shtml

Looking for a way to get "applebanadacantaloupe" (no spaces). Is there any native functionality within Apache SSI to accomplish this? An equivalent of something like concat or trim? I cannot find anything in the documentation but perhaps someone out there has solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't anything in the `include` module which will provide this functionality.

From the summary of the [module's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html):

> The processing is controlled by specially formatted SGML comments,
>   referred to as elements. These elements allow conditional text, the
>   inclusion of other files or programs, as well as the setting and
>   printing of environment variables.